# Spring equivalent of Guice's requireBinding

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

What is the equivalent of Guice's [`requireBinding`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html) in Spring?

For those familiar with Spring, but not Guice, here's what `requireBinding` is useful for:
Suppose you have 4 modules:

- `security`
  contains a `SignatureHelper` interface
- `web-api`
  depends on `security`
  contains REST API resources that make use of the `SignatureHelper`
- `web-ui`
  depends on `security` as well
  contains HTML resources that also make use of the `SignatureHelper`
- `webapp`
  depends on both `web-api` and `web-ui` (and transitively `security`)
  exists mostly to package both these modules into a single .war file
  it also contains an implementation of the `SignatureHelper` interface

Both `web-api` and `web-ui` won't be able to declare their own bindings of the `SignatureHelper`, as they don't even have a concrete implementation available. And even if they did, together they wouldn't be allowed to both declare the same binding twice.

This is why with Guice, both `web-api` and `web-ui` can simply specify a required dependency on the `SignatureHelper` class, and demand that the application in which their Guice modules are being loaded has previously bound one.

How can I accomplish the same thing in Spring?

Comment: Spring is has a completely different architecture and it is nearly impossible to find the exact equivalent. [`SecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) might be helpful?

Comment: `requireBinding` in Guice doesn't actually help in that scenario, though. `requireBinding` exists for when you have a binding that is *dynamically* required by a module. If your dependencies are statically discoverable (e.g. because your module provides a binding for a class that needs to inject `SignatureHelper`), then your module *already* requires a binding for `SignatureHelper`. If you omit the `requireBinding` call you will get the same effect, except with a *better error message*, because the error will point at the class(es) that actually depend on `SignatureHelper`.

Comment: @DanielPryden `requireBinding` gives me a better error message when my dependency graph is being evaluated, but it also offers tool support; meaning my IDE can understand that declaring a dependency on `SignatureHelper` is valid, even though it's being bound within the same module. It also helps document this binding dependency in code.